# Working with ReturnUrl and POST

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this function that lets a user add an "item" to the users basket. The item has a few properties, such as name and description. When a user clicks add, the object is posted to the  server and put in database.

However, if the user is not logged on, i want the user to be redirected to the login page (also possibilty to register), when logged on, I want the item to be added. This is generally the behavior of the returnURL-parameter wich functionality is default, but it obviously will not work if I need to provide parameters.

Any ideas on a good (cookieless) approach?

Comment: Can you use the session for this at all?

Comment: I'd rather use another solution, but i guess session is an option.

Comment: Are you using Asp.Net membership?

Comment: @CjCoax Yeas, I am using asp.net membership (with sql server)

Comment: have you seen `[Authorize]` attribute in MVC ?

Comment: @Yasser Yes, the method that saves the data uses [Authorize], this is why the user gets sent to the loginpage. This is the behavior I want, but I need to "tuck away" the parameters sent, so I can use it to create the actual item when the user has logged on.

Comment: how about saving the values in Session, I know it would not be the best solution, but its a way. Also you can use cookie, but it seems you dont want to for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

One of the simpliest way to do is using **Response.redirect(**"your_URL_with_params_here"**)** if user is not logged in. In your login page you can manipulate with params from URL like you need and if user pass authorisation you just do next steps you need.